# Form must be convertible to System.Web.UI.Page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I was making changes in my .aspx file, when IntelliSense complained:

"LSPForm must be convertible to System.Web.UI.Page".  Here's the @Page line I'm using:

```
<%@ Page AutoEventWireup="true" Codebehind="LSPForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="LSPForm" Language=""C#" MasterPageFile="MasterPage.master" Title="DMV: Marker Plate Notice" %>
```

The code-behind references .aspx variables that are defined on the .aspx page, but now cause errors of the form: "The name  does not exist in the current context," where  is a field defined in the .aspx page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can we see your code-behind?  It sounds like your base type got mangled/changed.

Answer (score 5):

If you did a direct copy and paste, you have too many quotes at the Language.

Answer (score 0):

so for me it was simple thing.  ReSharper had suggested removing the ": System.Web.UI.Page" at the end of the line below in my C# and gave me the error of the "must be convertible".  Sometimes smart tools are not so smart.  So I put the the line back to:

public partial class Valstamp : System.Web.UI.Page

and life was good.  Hope this silly simple mistake answer might help someone.